# Make a user give custom blacklisted words discordjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, discord, discord.js

I'm making a bot and I want the user to be able to give their own custom filtered words that contains profanity:

```js
//declare profanities
let Blacklist = ['bad', 'bad2', 'bad3']

  //profanity: deletes messages and DM's users
  for(let word of Blacklist){
    if(message.content.toLowerCase().includes(word)){
      message.delete()
      message.author.send("Keep the use of Profanity out of our server!")
      break;
      }
  }
```

How do I go by making the users add their own words to the array just by inputting it on discord

Comment: You will need some way to store the blacklisted words per user in a server side database. When a message is received in your server, identify the user and their blacklisted words and then apply the filter as required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sup Xattics, help is here.

The best way for them to store the array is by using a database or a JSON file. Text files can be used, but it's not the best way. In my opinion, using a database would be much simpler, if you start with an easy database wrapper. For beginners, [quick.db](https://www.npmjs.com/package/quick.db) would do the job for you. It uses sqlite3 which is fast and its functions are very simple. A small snippet of code that might help you:

```
// storing the word
const db = require('quick.db')
let wordtoadd = args[0] // program this how you prefer
db.push('guild.swearwords', phrase)

// removing the word
const db = require('quick.db')
let wordtoremove = args[0] // program this how you prefer
let dbinstance = db.get('guild.swearwords') // gets an instance first

const index = dbget.indexOf(wordtoremove);
if (index === -1) return; // error
dbinstance.splice(index, 1);
await db.set('guild.swearwords', dbget) // It removes the word from the array, then sets it back again.


// message event
const db = require('quick.db')
client.on("message", async message => {
  let dbget = await db.get("guild.swearwords")
  if(dbget.some(word => message.content.toLowerCase().includes(word))) {
     message.delete()
  }
}
```

Of course, quick.db isnt really the best option, but its great for starting and interacting with databases. Hope you learn something from this!

Comment: This has a problem: the usage of characters from [this wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IDN_homograph_attack) or other charatcers like Left-To-Rgiht-Override (which is invisible) breaks thing approach.